# Using a delayed variable value to as a length value in a substring

Tags: batch-file

I am extracting note sets from a log file.
The line number of the header to a set in the file is found via `FIND /V /N`
The note set is delimited with a line containing only "`@@@`"
I use `findstr` to return this line which returns as '`xxx:@@@`', e.g. '`14:@@@`' or '`149:@@@`' and so on.

in the snippet of code below, typical data for the variables on entry into the `FOR/IN` loop would be

- `_ndelm = "@@@"` ~ the delimiter marking the end of the note
- `_infil = "notes.log"` the file holding the dataset
- `_atpos` = the line position of the note header

During execution the local variables in the `enabledelayedexpansion` loop hold the following temporary values requiring !..! in the moment of processing:

- `strel`= the string delimiter line returned by `findstr` as above
- `numel`= the extracted line number from `strel`=='xxx', generally 1-4 chars long
- `end`  = will become the (integer) line number of the delimiter line

In this code snippet the `IF` statements are needed to get around my problem: I can't find a way to use `!end!` in a single `SET` statement, so the workaround is 4 `IF`s.:

```
SET _ndelm=@@@
SET /a _atpos=1
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=[]" %%i IN (`FINDSTR /b /l /n /c:%_ndelm% %_infil% `) DO (
SET strel=%%i
CALL stringlen %%i end & rem gets the character length of the delimiter line]
SET /a end-=4
IF [!end!] EQU [1] (SET numel=!strel:~0,1!)
IF [!end!] EQU [2] (SET numel=!strel:~0,2!)
IF [!end!] EQU [3] (SET numel=!strel:~0,3!)
IF [!end!] EQU [4] (SET numel=!strel:~0,4!)
SET /a end=!numel!
IF !end! GEQ %_atpos% GOTO fetchlines
)
```

Ideally, I would like to code something like this

```
(SET numel=!strel:~0,!end!!)
SET /a end=!numel!
```

I've hunted high and low to find a similar use case, but to no avail, and tried any number of  combinations of %'s and !'s empirically.

If anyone has a syntax I could use ~ that would be great :-)

Thanks

**file extract from the file:**

```
11/01/2020 16:05:29.87 *** DONE *** All Batches [LEFiles needing /r]
 find all batches that should not be run, apply the /r switch and amend 
 accordingly. Start at root and work down the main line before tackling the 
 side branches.
  ~ Main *** done ***
  ~ libs *** done ***
  ~ rest *** done ***
  ~
@@@
11/01/2020 15:18:47.02 >>> open >>> LEfiles runit [add a 'don't run!' switch]
 some batches just can't be -or shouldn't be- run from the help system.
 code a don't run switch [/r]=don't run
@@@
09/01/2020 10:12:52.83 *** DONE *** strcharrepl [bug] abend on "*" to " "
 error message '= % was unexpected at this time.' after returning from a call to
 nameFiledatetime which itself crashes on spaces - workaround for that needed
 Suspect it's the same problem - returning a string with spaces is the generic
 issue that needs a solution.
 Maybe always return with quotes and then strip those? 
 ~soln [strcharrepl] not much that can be done because redirection chars
  always act in re-dir ways. Added notes to provide guidance in use.
 ~soln [zFN] surround filename with quotes and replace spaces with backslashes
  before call, replace with spaces after.
@@@
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. In particular, all `set` commands  for the variables `_ndelm`, `_infil` etc.

Comment: I've got a problem with your logic. Why not just `FOR /f "delims=:" %%i IN ('FINDSTR /b /l /n /c:%_ndelm% %_infil%') do set "end=%%i"`?

Comment: [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) because `end` then becomes (eg) `149:@@@` and any attempt to use this as an end position gives a `Missing operator.` error. it works, but (of course) every iteration repeats the message and you can end up with screenfulls of error messages.

Comment: [@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) do you want a file extract as well?

Comment: no, `end` becomes (eg) `149`. Note `"delims=:"`

Comment: [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) Ah! missed the nuance ...  **of course**. _stop at the colon_. simplicity is always obvious in retrospect! Thanks ~ that collapses the code completely :-) Still, learned something really useful from [@Jeb's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) answer too. Two medals in one day.

Comment: [@Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) The nuance ...  **measurably** _faster at scale_. Thanks guys, both yourself Stephan and [@Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb).  Take the rest of Sunday off ;-) ~c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
For %%e in (!end!) Do set numel=!strel:~0,%%e!
```

The trick is to use a for loop parameter, because the parameter is expanded before the delayed expansion will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the various contributors, the code snippet simplified to:

```
FOR /f "delims=:" %%i IN ('FINDSTR /b /l /n /c:%_ndelm% %_infil%') do (
  set "end=%%i"
  IF !end! GEQ %_atpos% GOTO fetchlines
)
```

which improved readability and performance.
The answer to the Question posed is the accepted answer from [@Jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb).